# Xamarin-iOS crash: Since iOS 13 our app has been crashing whenever voice over is turned on

Tags: ios, xamarin, voiceover

I've been able te reproduce it while using the Xcode accessibility inspector.
The concerning page holds numerous UI elements which used to work fine with voice over.
I've been looking all over the internet but up to now it feels like we're the only one with this problem.

`Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSRangeException Reason: NSConcreteAttributedString attributedSubstringFromRange:: Out of bounds
Native stack trace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3de6e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff512539b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   Foundation                          0x00007fff25a0dfb6 -[NSAttributedString attributedSubstringFromRange:replacingCharactersInRanges:numberOfRanges:withString:] + 0
3   UIKit                               0x000000011a6595c2 __58-[UITextViewAccessibility _accessibilityParagraphElements]_block_invoke + 216
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff25966dc3 -[NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:] + 2104
5   UIKit                               0x000000011a6593e9 -[UITextViewAccessibility _accessibilityParagraphElements] + 436
6   UIKit                               0x000000011a6577a8 -[UITextViewAccessibility accessibilityElements] + 45
7   UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486f8d9a -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityElements] + 69
8   UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff4871b602 -[NSObjectAccessibility accessibilityElementCount] + 81
9   UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486f8821 -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityHasOrderedChildren] + 46
10  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486ef186 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilityShouldBeAddedToViewChildrenWithOptions:] + 214
11  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486efabb -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 164
12  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486eff45 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 1326
13  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486eff45 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 1326
14  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486eff45 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 1326
15  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486eff45 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 1326
16  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486eff45 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 1326
17  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486eff45 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 1326
18  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486eff45 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 1326
19  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486eff45 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 1326
20  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486eff45 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 1326
21  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486eff45 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 1326
22  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486eff45 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 1326
23  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486f03de +[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilityElementsAndContainersDescendingFromViews:options:sorted:] + 507
24  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486f0b2d -[UIApplication(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilityViewChildrenWithOptions:referenceWindow:] + 561
25  UIKit                               0x000000011a618588 -[UIApplicationAccessibility _accessibilityElementFirst:last:forFocus:allowScrolling:] + 206
26  UIKit                               0x000000011a61cb2a -[UIApplicationAccessibility _iosAccessibilityAttributeValue:] + 728
27  UIAccessibility                     0x00007fff486e40da _copyAttributeValueCallback + 432
28  AXRuntime                           0x00007fff2e735816 ___AXXMIGCopyAttributeValue_block_invoke + 46
29  AXRuntime                           0x00007fff2e7356e3 _handleNonMainThreadCallback + 55
30  AXRuntime                           0x00007fff2e7355a6 _AXXMIGCopyAttributeValue + 286
31  AXRuntime                           0x00007fff2e72e0f3 _XCopyAttributeValue + 269
32  AXRuntime                           0x00007fff2e745ba6 mshMIGPerform + 237
33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da2449 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 41
34  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1a48 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 472
35  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9c474 __CFRunLoopRun + 2228
36  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9b8a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
37  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38c39bbe GSEventRunModal + 139
38  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49325968 UIApplicationMain + 1605
39  ???                                 0x0000000109b53095 0x0 + 4457836693
40  ???                                 0x0000000109b52de3 0x0 + 4457836003
41  ???                                 0x00000001093c69f3 0x0 + 4449921523
42  Mono                                0x0000000103204641 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1569
43  Mono                                0x00000001033f8cd8 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 136
44  Mono                                0x00000001033ff045 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 117
45  Mono                                0x000000010325f16c mono_jit_exec + 364
46  MHMobileAppsNewsAppiOS              0x0000000102c958cd xamarin_main + 2685
47  MHMobileAppsNewsAppiOS              0x0000000102c52237 main + 71
48  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff520ce1fd start + 1

at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (System.IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.3.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:406
at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (System.IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/runtime/Delegates.generated.cs:128
at at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception(intptr)
at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.3.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.3.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65
at MH.MobileApps.NewsApp.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0001c] in /Users/erland/Projects/Mediahuis/projects/NewsApp/NewsApp.iOS/Main.cs:15`

Comment: Not sure if this would help but my best guess is that you have a dynamic UITextView, using another StackOverflow question posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204842/uitextview-with-voiceover I could deduce that you can try altering your textView.accessibilityTraits to something dynamic like "adjustable" or something that suits it better. Please refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/uiaccessibility/accessibility_traits